# feed composite inputs to model

Tags: python, cntk

I need to feed an image and a vector sampled from normal distribution simultaneously. As the image dataset I'm using is too large, I create a ImageDeserializer for that part. But I also need to add random vector (sampled from numpy normal distribution), to the input map before feed it to the network. Is there any way to achieve this?

I also test:

```
mb_data = reader_train.next_minibatch(mb_size, input_map=input_map)
mb_data[random_input_node] = np.random.normal((mb_size, 100))
```

but get the following error:

> TypeError: cannot convert value of dictionary to N4CNTK13MinibatchDataE

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I'd recommend an indirect method to achieve this: [creating a custom UserMinibatchSource](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/extend.html#user-defined-minibatch-sources) that will define streams for both images and random vectors, and automatically return both in each minibatch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved with the following snippet to feed data to trainer:

```
mb_data = reader_train.next_minibatch(mb_size, input_map=input_map)
z = np.random.normal(mb_size)
my_trainer.train_minibatch({feature_image: mb_data[image].data, feature_z: z})
```

Also thanks to @mewahl. Defining new reader is another suitable way to solve the problem, and I think it must be faster than what I have done.